# Functions scope in JS file and how to order them

Tags: jquery, html

I've got this JS code, in the same shown order:

```
function init(){
    //Initialize stuff
    $('#specificUl > li').click();
    //...
}
//Click event handler
function clickHandler(){
    //Do some other stuff
    //...
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
    //Click event handler defined
    $('li').click(clickHandler);
    //...
});
```

Since click handler is defined on `ready` event I guess the calling of `click` event in `init` function is not going to work which is what's already happening but I'm not sure. How should I reorganize the code to make it work?

Comment: Shouldn't `$('li').click(clickHandler);` be inside `init`? Binding event handlers is part of the initialization...

Comment: That's a good point and should make `ready` handler clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(clickHandler);
    //....
    init();
});
```

switch click handler with init

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Click event handler defined
    $('li').click(clickHandler);

    init();
    //...
});
```

If you are only going to call the handler on `li` then you don't need a seperate method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Click event handler defined
    $('li').click(clickHandler);

    $('#specificUl > li').click();
    //...
});
```